# How do I Import js file to React js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

JavaScript File.

```
const signUpButton = document.getElementById('signUp');
const signInButton = document.getElementById('signIn');
const container = document.getElementById('container');

signUpButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.add("right-panel-active");
});

signInButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.remove("right-panel-active");
});
```

I have this javascript Code, I want to use this in my React file.
This is my React js file Code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
// import './js/main'

class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="form-container sign-up-container">
        <form action="#">
            <h1>Create Account</h1>
            <div class="social-container">
                <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f" style={{color: 'blue'}} aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" style={{color: 'red'}} aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" style={{color: 'blue'}} aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
            <span>or use your email for registration</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <button>Sign Up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="form-container sign-in-container">
        <form action="#">
            <h1>Sign in</h1>
            <div class="social-container">
            <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f" style={{color: 'blue'}} aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" style={{color: 'red'}} aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" style={{color: 'blue'}} aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
            <span>or use your account</span>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
            <button>Sign In</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-container">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
                <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
                <p>To keep connected with us please login with your personal info</p>
                <button class="ghost" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
                <h1>Hello, Friend!</h1>
                <p>Enter your personal details and start journey with us</p>
                <button class="ghost" id="signUp">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login
```

In this code there onclick events for scrolling the login form and get the signup page.
How do I use Javascript to perform click events.  I am new to React. Help me to get out of this.

Comment: [Read the introductory tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#making-an-interactive-component) before resorting to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Add this code to the ```componentDidMount``` hook. Don't forget to remove event listners  on the ```componentWillUnmount```

Comment: Those two pieces of code may not work well together.

Comment: You should avoid directly touching the DOM if you are using react

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing the following

1. Create two separate components for `signUpButton.js` and `signInButton.js`, each. These components should include their respective event handlers as well
2. Import these two components into your main component (your main React.js file) and use them.

> import { SignUpButton } from './signUpButton.js'

> import { SignInButton } from './signUpButton.js'

Right now, in your JavaScript file, you are trying to directly access DOM elements using `document.getElementById`. This is not recommended in React

Its important that you go through the core react concepts here and understand these thoroughly. This will definitely help you in the long run
https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html

Event Handling in React
https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#events

Comment: How do I handle Events for Above code, Can you help me how do I handle Events.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Login extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {addClass: false}
      }
      toggle() {
        this.setState({addClass: !this.state.addClass});
      }
    render() {
        let Class = ['container'];
    if(this.state.addClass) {
      Class.push('right-panel-active');
    }
        return (
            <div>
                <div className={Class.join(' ')} id="container">
```

Putting this is did a great Job to me. Working as Expected.

```
<button className="ghost" id="signIn" onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}>{this.state.addClass}Log In</button>
```

And Calling this on Button click. Solved this after doing tones of Research. Feeling  very Happy as new Beginner React js Developer.